# How to perform a mobile search

Tags: discussion, support

Ive looked everywhere on the android SE mobile interface and I cannot, for the life of me, find any way whatsoever to perform a search of previous SE questions without resorting to exiting the program and using a Google search.

What gives? Is it buried somewhere? Am I missing something obvious?

Should i be punished for not performing a search prior to asking a question if i cannot perform a search of SE explicitly?

Comment: To be clear, are you talking about the mobile browser version, or about the iOS / android mobile apps obtained through the relevant app stores?

Comment: Android application

Comment: I just deleted the argumentative parts of the comment discussion; there wasn't much of anything useful in it anyway. Let's put that behind us and focus on the question.

Comment: @DavidZ thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the third line of the mobile version of the Physics SE page, there is "All questions" in bold face. When you wait for the page to fully load, a magnifying glass icon appears on the right side from "All questions". Clicking at this icon gives the same search box that you find immediately in the upper right corner of the desktop edition of the page.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh...i think my issue was that i had been scrolled down and then was looking for the search.  Thanks for being kind and helpful.  I feel pretty dumb now!

Comment: I didn't see it "immediately", either. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear to me, at all, what you think is the problem - but then again, I don't normally use the app. However, I just installed it, clicked on the menu button at top left, and selected a random site, which gives this page:

[image]

Unless the site homepage within the app looks different on your device (in which case you need to provide some screenshots) I really don't see how one would manage to miss the search interface.

Comment: I take it, given the downvote, this does not answer your question and you'll be adding clarifying information to the question shortly.